# Why would PayPal's IPN return the status as 'Completed' when it's on hold?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using Express Checkout, and the response from DoExpressCheckout returns the following parameters:

```
PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE = INSTANT
PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS = COMPLETED_FUNDS_HELD
PENDINGREASON = NONE
REASONCODE = NONE
HOLDDECISION = PAYMENTHOLD
```

However, the IPN that's sent along doesn't make any reference to the funds being held. The `payment_status` is set as `Completed` and there's [no mention of a parameter that might signify an issue in the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) for the IPN values.

How can I ensure that I only react once the payment has been taken out of review, and is no longer being held?

(Note: I need to resolve how to handle this in the IPN, *not* the underlying problem with the account, as this is a historical issue that I need to prevent from happening again for any reason)

Comment: You should open a case with PayPal about this.

Answer (score 0):

IPN are showing the transaction status during the time it was happen, in your case, the payment are done, completed which means, the money was initiated from the buyer account into your account, but due to some issues/reasons the transfer of the said money was pending. Some security check has caused the transaction funds being held

In IPN payment status, it was showing that COMPLETED_FUNDS_HELD which means there is a money come into your account but then it was held due to some reason where only PayPal knows.

This payment will be release in a few days, and until that time, if you handling the payment carefully from your website dashboard order, it shouldn't be any issue because normally PayPal only hold it for a few days.

Until this time, I written this, PayPal hasn't got any solution for this type of held because it was an account related issue where IPN are not feed to the get the update.

Comment: Sure, I understand that it was held temporarily, but I need to know that it was held in the IPN so that I can delay some actions which must run only once when the payment has been actually finalised. Do they just _not_ provide that info at all in the IPN? That seems like yet another massive limitation!

Comment: The only flags/indicator that you can use was the PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS where it include if the payment success was in held in the account, however there will be no sub-sequence IPN if the money was released on the account.